# Why doesn't jQuery pass the correct value to HTML?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my code it's like a for loop for count and countin variables .. in last loop every thing is okay and it return correct value but it can't return past values .

what is the problem ?

this is my code :

```
@{
    int count = 1;
    int countin = 110;
    }

@foreach (var item in Model) {

<script>
    obj = {};
    obj[@count] = Math.round(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProgressPercent) * 268 / 100);

    var objin = {};
    objin[@count] = "-" + obj[@count] + "px 0";

    var jq3 = jQuery.noConflict();
    jq3(document).ready(function () {

        jq3("#bar-pro-@count").css({ "background-position": objin[@count] });

        if (obj[@count] == 100) {
            jq3("#bar-pro-@count").css({ "background-image": "none" });
            jq3("#bar-pro-@countin").css({ "background-image": "none" });
        };

    });
</script>

<div class="bar-t"><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) | در مرحله : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phase)</b></div>
<div class="bar-100">
<div class="bar" id="bar-pro-@countin">
</div>
<div class="bar-pro" id="bar-pro-@count"></div>
<div class="bar-num"><script> document.write(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProgressPercent) + "%");</script></div>
</div>
    count = count + 1;
    countin = countin + 10;
}
```

and after rendering in HTML :

```
<script>
    obj = {};
    obj[1] = Math.round(12 * 268 / 100);    
    var objin = {};    
    objin[1] = "-" + obj[1] + "px 0";
    var jq3 = jQuery.noConflict();    
    jq3(document).ready(function () {
        jq3("#bar-pro-1").css({ "background-position": objin[1] });
        if (obj[1] == 100) {
            jq3("#bar-pro-1").css({ "background-image": "none" });
            jq3("#bar-pro-110").css({ "background-image": "none" });
        };
    });

</script>
<div class="bar-t"><b>Progress</b></div>
<div class="bar-100">
<div class="bar" id="bar-pro-110">
</div>
<div class="bar-pro" id="bar-pro-1"></div>
<div class="bar-num"><script> document.write(12 + "%");</script></div>
</div>
```

this is just one of the loops. If you want I can put full code and results. 
NOTE : last value is correct and it applied to css but past values for CSS don't work .

what is the problem ?

**NOTE : I found problem. Because obj and objin arrays are in loop . they shoud be out of loop .**

Comment: I found problem ..
because obj and objin arrays are in loop . they shoud be out of loop

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem here:

```
 if (objin[1] == 100) ...
```

You are comparing this value to a number. Since you're appending "px 0" to this value, it will always be a string. This comparison will always fail.

```
objin[1] = "-" + obj[1] + "px 0";
```

Comment: I fix it .. obj[1] == 100 I compare it with a number now . but does not work .

Comment: According to your code it will actually be "-100px 0" which != 100

Comment: I fix it @Diodeus . my arrays are into loop . I put them out of loop and it works now properly .